# Processing optimization Spring

Tags: java, spring

I need to use values from db in calculation.
Is it correct to use private field to have access on list of values in any position without repeatedly request to the database because it's slow down process?

For example

```
@Component
public class SomeClass {

// some dependency
private final RecordDao recordDao;

private List<String> records;

public SomeClass(RecordDao recordDao) {
    this.recordDao = recordDao;
}

public void process(List<String> data) {
    records = recordDao.getAll();
    
    // some code
    method();
    method2();
    
}

private void method(/* some param */) {
    for () {
        for (String s : records) {
            // do smt
        }
    }
}

private void method2(/* some param */) {
    for (String s : records) {
        // do smt
    }
}
```

}

Comment: So whats your question?

Comment: I'm wondering if it's correct to use the field for storing data from the database so that during the operation, only once access the storage and then use the class field in which the values are written ​​for the current operation

Comment: In general: No, it is not correct to store data in a member variable (`records` in this case) as a way to pass that data to other methods you are calling in the same class. Instead, pass the data as arguments to the methods.